# Why does a buyer-employment contract dominate a spot contract in this example (Bolton & Dewatripont 11.1.2.5, p497)

Tags: contract-theory

I'm working through Bolton and Dewatripont, Section 11.1.2, and have some questions about material in 11.2.5 on the bottom of page 497. I've tried to abbreviate the setup below, followed by my question.

> There are two periods and a buyer and a seller. The seller can provide service $a_i\, (i = 1, \ldots n)$ in the second period, only one of which the buyer will need (service is observable/verifiable). If they do not transact in the second period, both parties get zero. If they trade at price $P_i$, then they get \begin{gather}U(a_i, \theta_l) - P_i \tag{buyer}\\P_i - \psi(a_i, \theta_l) \tag{seller}\end{gather} where $\theta_l$ is one of $N\geq n$ possible states of nature, realized between the first and second periods. The buyer can make some investment $I$ in the first period to increase her utility $U = U(a_i, \theta_i, I)$, and to simplify, B&D assume
> \begin{gather}
> U(a_i, \theta_l, I) \in \{0, \phi(I), \Phi(I)\}\\
> \psi(a_i, \theta_l) \in \{0, c, C\} \text{ with}\\
> 0 < \Phi(I) - C < \phi(I) - c < \Phi(I) - c < \Phi(I)
> \end{gather}
> and
> \begin{gather}
> U(a_i, \theta_l, I) = 0 \Rightarrow \psi(a_i, \theta_l) = 0\\
> U(a_i, \theta_l, I) = \phi(I) \Rightarrow \psi(a_i, \theta_l) = c\\
> U(a_i, \theta_l, I) = \Phi(I) \Rightarrow \psi(a_i, \theta_l) = C
> \end{gather}
> meaning that valuable services, in any state, are also the most costly. Assume there's always one service $a_i$ where the maximum surplus $\phi(I)$ can be realized and that any surplus is divided equally between the buyer and seller.
>
> B&D then walk through their payoffs from using a spot contract, sales contract, buyer-employment contract, and seller-employment contract. I only describe the first three.
>
> 1. **Spot contract** where the two transact in the second period after the state is realized and the buyer chooses $I$ to maximize $(\phi(I)-c)/2 - I$ and so $$\phi'(I^s) = 2 \tag{Spot contract}$$ with the buyer under-investing.
> 2. **Sales contract** of the form $[a_i, P_i]$ where, in the first period, the buyer/seller agree to exchange $a_i$ for price $P_i$. If the maximum surplus can be realized in the state of nature, i.e., $U(a_i, \theta_l, I) = \phi(I)$ and $\psi(a_i, \theta_l) = c$ then they execute the contract. The buyer gets $\phi(I) - P_i$ and the seller gets $P_i - c$.
>    Otherwise, they renegotiate* and agree upon action $a_j$ where $j\neq i$ but $U(a_j, \theta_l, I) = \phi(I)$. The surplus is $(\phi(I) - c) - (\Phi(I) - C)$ when $U(a_i, \theta_l, I) = \Phi(I)$ and $\psi(a_i, \theta_l) = C$ and $\phi(I) - c$ otherwise. B&D assume equiprobable states of nature, with only one of the $n$ states conducive to the maximum surplus and the remaining $n-1$ states divided equally between the two aforementioned ones.
>    The buyer's expected utility is
>    \begin{gather}
>    \frac{1}{n}(\phi(I) - P_i) + \frac{n-1}{2n}\Big\{\Big(\Phi(I) - P_i + \frac{(\phi(I) - c) - (\Phi(I) - C)}{2}\Big) + \Big(- P_i + \frac{(\phi(I) - c)}{2}\Big)\Big\} - I
>    \end{gather}
>    with the buyer's optimal $I$ fulfilling
>    \begin{equation}
>    \phi'(I^S)(\frac{n+1}{n}) + \Phi'(I^S)(\frac{2n-1}{n}) = 2 \tag{Sales}
>    \end{equation}
> 3. **Buyer-employment** In the first period, the seller agrees to provide the buyer with a subset of services $A$ at price $P(a)$ for providing service $a \in A$. Since all services are symmetric, assume $A$ includes everything and $P(a) = P$. The buyer would always choose an inefficient costly action $j\neq i$ where $U(a_j, \theta_l) = \Phi(I)$. They would then renegotiate to a contract $a_i$ and split the surplus, giving the buyer a payoff of $\Phi(I) - P + (1/2)[(\phi(I) - c) - (\Phi(I) - C)] - I$. The buyer's optimal investment then satisfies
>    \begin{gather}
>    \phi'(I^{BE}) + \Phi'(I^{BE}) = 2 \tag{Buyer-Employment}
>    \end{gather}
>    * <sub>I think B&D make a typo, writing $U(a_{\color{red}i}, \theta_l, I) = \phi(I)$</sub>

**Question 1** B&D write that buyer employment contract dominates the sales contract when $[\phi'(I^S) - \Phi'(I^S)]/n > 0$. How do they find this? I rewrote the optimal sales FOC as
\begin{equation}
\phi'(I^S) + \Phi'(I^S)  + \frac{1}{n}\Big(\phi'(I^S) - \Phi'(I^S)\Big) + \Phi'(I^S) = 2.
\end{equation}
but I'm not sure what that gets me. If the last term on the right side, $\Phi'(I^S)$, were dropped  and $[\phi'(I^S) - \Phi'(I^S)]/n > 0$ then $\phi'(I^S) + \Phi'(I^S) < 2$. Does that mean there would be more investment under the sales contract? Or, does the level of investment depend on the ``weight'' assigned to $\phi'$ and $\Phi'$ in the buyer's marginal payoff from investment?

**Question 2**: B&D note the buyer under-invests in the spot contract. Would the optimal investment be $\max_I \phi(I) - c - I \Rightarrow \phi'(I) = 1$? Related to this, on page 497, B&D say that the spot contract is weakly dominated by the buyer employment contract. It's obvious that the latter would encourage more investment, but B&D also write that there is no over-investment under any contract, though this may be the case if $\Phi'(I) > \phi'(I)$. What do they mean here by over-investment?